# Is "take many people, for instance, who + Verb" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

This sentence is taken from a sample essay but since I only see this sentence in speaking, I do not know if this is a complete sentence or not.

"Take many people, for instance, who have been working under severe condition so as to save up for something they would otherwise be unable to afford."
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The only actual grammatical *error* is the use of the form *condition* where the plural form *conditions* is required; however, the sentence is very awkward, and not very clear. (Also, it doesn't really say anything on its own; but I'll assume that it appeared in a context that provided the substance.)

A more natural and "essay-like" phrasing might be:

> For instance, consider the many people who accept poor working conditions in exchange for better pay, in order to be able to afford things that they otherwise could not.

(assuming, of course, that this indeed matches what you're trying to say).